# Oracle default order by behavior

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle12c

In select query when we add order by on some column and in the returned resultset that column contains same value for some of the rows what will be the sorting behavior of those rows?

Comment: Possibly not defined, you can do that yourself adding another column to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: The order of rows not defined by an `ORDER BY` is arbitrary / undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no defined sorting behavior, in general, at least the ANSI standard does not require a database vendor to provide one.  You *might* find that a certain order tends to be obeyed, but the best thing to do here would be to just a second sort level to break the tie, i.e. use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    col1,
    col2;    -- break the tie
```

So if your data were:

```
col1 | col2
1    | 1
1    | 2
2    | 4
2    | 1
```

then the above query would return a sorted result as you expect.

Comment: *"no defined sorting behavior, **in general**"* I don't think there is *any* vendor that has a defined sorting behavior for when `ORDER BY` is missing or non-unique, because sorting is a performance drain, and none of them would want to slow down the query to present an ordering that the client wouldn't care about.

Comment: @Andreas . . . There actually *are* cases.  MySQL has guaranteed the ordering in a `group by` query, although that behavior is deprecated.  Less traditional database products, such as MS Access, might also guarantee the ordering under some circumstances, but I doubt that is actually documented.

Comment: *"I doubt that is actually documented"* If not documented, then it is "not **defined**". Just because a certain implementation might be *currently* predictable, doesn't make it "defined", since an implementation may be changed without notice. And if not documented, where does the "guarantee" come from?

Comment: Even for MySQL, with its (deprecated) default ordering for statements with `GROUP BY`, the documentation says to add `ORDER BY NULL` to prevent that behavior, so any `ORDER BY` will eliminate that default ordering, so when the question ask *"when we add order by on some column"* it means that MySQL does not have a defined ordering beyond the column(s) listed in the `ORDER BY`, even if a `GROUP BY` lists more columns.